# What is the translation for "offset printing" in Portuguese?

Tags: tradução, tradução-inglês

I am trying to get the correct usage for "offset printing" in Portuguese.

Here are a few scenarios to help gauge my idea:

> Offset printing is no longer the king in print industry.
>
> Digital and offset printing; both offer advantages and disadvantages.
>
> The future of Offset vs. Digital Printing

If I had just the word "OFFSET", what would I use in Portuguese to reflect its meaning in the print industry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you target a professional audience, the only possible translation is `impressão offset`, because that's how designers and printing services have become used to calling it.

The idea behind offset printing is that ink is not directly applied to the substrate (paper, fabric, etc), unlike most other printing processes (such as inkjet printing). Instead, it is applied to a set of cylinders before finally reaching its destination (usually paper) and forming images. `Offset`, in this context, means `deslocada` or `desalinhada`.

Comment: Exatamente.  Sempre vi o termo "impressão offset" em jornais e revistas, desde a época em que eu não tinha a menor ideia do que se tratava. +1